# How do I filter an object array in Typescript by a property in a forEach loop and return a Component with props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and Typescript, and I'm having trouble rendering a set of components that each take an array of cars (for this example) and a year.

I have an array of n items coming from an external source, and I want to group them by year.

```
[
      {
        "modelYear": {
          "model": "Accord",
          "year": 2016
        },
        "make": "Honda"
      },
      {
        "modelYear": {
          "model": "Tacoma",
          "year": 2017
        },
        "make": "Toyota"
      }
]
```

In my render function

```
const uniqueYears = cars
.map(c=> c.modelYear.year)
.filter((value, index, self)=> self.indexOf(value) === index);
return(
  <div>
    uniqueYears.forEach((element)=> {
    <Cars year={element} carList={cars.filter(x=> x.modelYear.year === element)} />
   }
  </div>
```

The carList property is typed to an interface that corresponds with the cars data.
My Linter is highlighting the `x.modelYear.year === element` and returning the error "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'Requireable ' have no overlap."

If I remove the call to my Component and just replace it with an < h3 >{element}< /h3 > within the forEach, React just renders `uniqueYears.forEach(element=>);` I am definitely using the wrong syntax somewhere...

Edit: I would like to get this component to render a Cars component for each year in the uniqueYears array. Each Cars component has a props year:number, and carList:car[]. The carList should be an array filtered from the main cars array by year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` just iterates the list. You want `map`, which will iterate the list and collect the results as a list.

You want something like this:

```
<div>
    {uniqueYears.map(element => (
    <Cars
        year={element}
        carList={cars.filter(x => x.modelYear.year === element)}
    />
    ))}
</div>
```

`uniqueYears.map()` will take a list of years, and return `Array<Cars>`, which is a valid JSX child.

Comment: Thank you! I also wasn't using the curly braces/parens correctly